# Wordpress dashboard is accessible from my PC but redirects to 404 on my laptop

Tags: wordpress, dashboard, wp-admin

as you can see in the title, I am able to login my Wordpress Website dashboard with no problem at all, on my Desktop. I've been doing the changes and security/plugin/theme updates using my Desktop. What I want to do right now is to do the same on my macbook. I want to be able to do the same from my macbook but I find it weird that on my PC, the dashboard is operational but on my macbook and my gf's laptop it redirects to the 404 error page.

I've tried clearing the cache upon doing some reading and saw some post about deleting the .hta access file but I am confused as to how files on my ftp is working on my desktop but not for my laptop.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you for taking the time to read!

Comment: Hi Haris, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Perhaps there is a problem in your url slug or your .htaccess configuration may be wrong.

Comment: Hello Shahiq, thanks for replying, is it possible scenario that the .htaccess configuration on the ftp works for only my desktop but not on other machines?

Comment: Yes that is a possible, since it may be blocking other IPs. You can test you .htaccess file using this util https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Thank you again Shahiq, will test it out

Comment: @shahiq572

below is the result of my test

https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=1a567638-0dc6-43f9-a34d-d346a1db8cc6

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I had a plugin conflict that changes my url dashboard slug for security purposes. A different developer created this website and had this plugin installed and it took me longer than I care to admit to notice this.